# Pandas: building a column with self-referencing past values

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I need to generate a column that starts with an initial value, and then is generated by a function that includes past values of that column. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,5,2,7,8,16,16,16]})
df['b'] = 0
df.ix[0, 'b'] = 1
df

    a  b
0   1  1
1   1  0
2   5  0
3   2  0
4   7  0
5   8  0
6  16  0
7  16  0
8  16  0
```

Now, I want to generate the rest of the column 'b' by taking the minimum of the previous row and adding two. One solution would be

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.ix[i, 'b'] = df.ix[i-1, :].min() + 2
```

Resulting in the desired output

```
    a   b
0   1   1
1   1   3
2   5   3
3   2   5
4   7   4
5   8   6
6  16   8
7  16  10
8  16  12
```

Does pandas have a 'clean' way to do this? Preferably one that would vectorize the computation?

Comment: I can't think of a way that doesn't involve iteration. But I will say that you don't have to use `.ix[]`; you can just have `df.b[i] = df.iloc[i-1].min() + 2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pandas` doesn't have a great way to handle general recursive calculations.  There may be some trick to vectorize it, but if you can take the dependency, this is relatively painless and very fast with `numba`.

```
@numba.njit
def make_b(a):
    b = np.zeros_like(a)
    b[0] = 1
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        b[i] = min(b[i-1], a[i-1]) + 2

    return b

df['b'] = make_b(df['a'].values)

df
Out[73]: 
    a   b
0   1   1
1   1   3
2   5   3
3   2   5
4   7   4
5   8   6
6  16   8
7  16  10
8  16  12
```